# Patch a JSON object using dynamic / ExpandoObject with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, dynamic-programming

### Background

Recently, I was making some updates to an "older" library that would handle PATCH-style modifications to an object that is persisted in a JSON format on our document-storage databases (e.g., CosmosDB).

I took a fresh approach of this, and started on a blank slate and decided to make use of the `DynamicObjectConverter` which was introduced back in [late 2020](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/42097) to the `System.Text.Json` library.

The goal is to handle a PATCH operation to an existing JSON object.

For example from an existing JSON document with:

```json
{
  "id": "e001",
  "name": "foo"
}
```

with a patch operation of

```json
{ "name": "bar" }
```

the result:

```json
{
  "id": "e001",
  "name": "bar"
}
```

I also wanted to be able to handle adding additional new properties to a collection of existing JSON documents (as a sweeping task) making patch updates across various documents that all have different schemas (hail schema-less DBs!). Such as adding a `metadata`, or `isHidden` property to all JSON documents.

### The Extension Class

There are 5 methods to the extension class.

> This question contains the complete class, you just need to put these 5 methods into a single `static class`.

###### DynamicUpdate() Method

The main extension method that extends the `IDictionary<string, object` type (which is commonly found in our code as `ExpandoObject` type implementation)

```csharp
internal static JsonElement DynamicUpdate(
    this IDictionary<string, object> entity,
    JsonDocument doc,
    bool addPropertyIfNotExists = false,
    bool useTypeValidation = true,
    JsonDocumentOptions options = default)
{
    if (doc == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(doc));
    if (doc.RootElement.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Object) 
        throw new NotSupportedException("Only objects are supported.");

    foreach (JsonProperty jsonProperty in doc.RootElement.EnumerateObject())
    {
        string propertyName = jsonProperty.Name;
        JsonElement newElement = doc.RootElement.GetProperty(propertyName);
        bool hasProperty = entity.TryGetValue(propertyName, out object oldValue);

        // sanity checks
        JsonElement? oldElement = null;
        if (oldValue != null)
        {
            if (!oldValue.GetType().IsAssignableTo(typeof(JsonElement))) 
                throw new ArgumentException($"Type mismatch. Must be {nameof(JsonElement)}.", nameof(entity));
            oldElement = (JsonElement)oldValue;
        }
        if (!hasProperty && !addPropertyIfNotExists) continue;
        entity[propertyName] = GetNewValue(
            oldElement, newElement, propertyName, 
            addPropertyIfNotExists, useTypeValidation, options);
    }
    using JsonDocument finalDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(JsonSerializer.Serialize(entity));
    return finalDoc.RootElement.Clone();
}
```

###### GetNewValue() Method

This method gets the value (recursively for object properties) and also deals with validation based on the passed in options as arguments.

```csharp
private static JsonElement GetNewValue(
    JsonElement? oldElementNullable, 
    JsonElement newElement, 
    string propertyName,
    bool addPropertyIfNotExists,
    bool useTypeValidation,
    JsonDocumentOptions options)
{
    if (oldElementNullable == null) return newElement.Clone();
    JsonElement oldElement = (JsonElement)oldElementNullable;

    // type validation
    if (useTypeValidation && !IsValidType(oldElement, newElement)) 
        throw new ArgumentException($"Type mismatch. The property '{propertyName}' must be of type '{oldElement.ValueKind}'.", nameof(newElement));

    // recursively go down the tree for objects
    if (oldElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Object)
    {
        string oldJson = oldElement.GetRawText();
        string newJson = newElement.ToString();
        IDictionary<string, object> entity = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(oldJson);
        return DynamicUpdate(entity, newJson, addPropertyIfNotExists, useTypeValidation, options);
    }

    return newElement.Clone();
}
```

###### IsValidType() Method

This method handles the validation for types. (i.e. trying to replace a `string` with an `int` will return false.

```csharp
private static bool IsValidType(JsonElement oldElement, JsonElement newElement)
{
    if (newElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Null) return true;
    
    // 'true' --> 'false'
    if (oldElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.True && newElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.False) return true;
    // 'false' --> 'true'
    if (oldElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.False && newElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.True) return true;
    
    // type validation
    return (oldElement.ValueKind == newElement.ValueKind);
}
```

###### IsValidJsonPropertyName() Method

This method just a quick way to make sure there isn't a totally malformed property name.

```csharp
private static bool IsValidJsonPropertyName(string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return false;

    // this is validation for our specific use case (C#)
    // note that the official docs don't prohibit this though.
    // https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(value[i])) continue;
        switch (value[i])
        {
            case '-':
            case '_':
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

###### Overloaded DynamicUpdate() Method

An overloaded method so that passing in a JSON string is also possible for tests, etc.

```csharp
internal static JsonElement DynamicUpdate(
    this IDictionary<string,
    object> entity,
    string patchJson,
    bool addPropertyIfNotExists = false,
    bool useTypeValidation = true,
    JsonDocumentOptions options = default)
{
    using JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(patchJson, options);
    return DynamicUpdate(entity, doc, addPropertyIfNotExists, useTypeValidation, options);
}
```

### How to use it

Here is a sample snippet to test the extension method.

```csharp
string original = @"{""foo"":[1,2,3],""parent"":{""childInt"":1},""bar"":""example""}"; 
string patch    = @"{""foo"":[9,8,7],""parent"":{""childInt"":9,""childString"":""woot!""},""bar"":null}";
Console.WriteLine(original);

// change this value to see the different types of patching method
bool addPropertyIfNotExists = false; 

ExpandoObject expandoObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(original);

// patch it!
expandoObject.DynamicUpdate(patch, addPropertyIfNotExists);
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(expandoObject));
```

> **Note:** For the example above, the JSON is a string, but in practice reading in the document comes as some form of a UTF8 binary stream, which is where the `JsonDocument` shines.

> **Important Note:** Keep in mind that property names are case sensitive, so `foo` and `FoO` are unique and valid property names. It would be trivial to add a method to support ignoring case, but in my use-case this is the desired use.

## Question for code review

It would be interesting to know if there are any better design patterns that can minimize the back-and-fourth of serializing the inner objects and materializing it as a `JsonElement` that happens in recursive section of the code found in the `GetNewValue()` method.

For a large object nested JSON object, there is a lot of packing up and cloning of the `JsonElement` struct. It's quite uncommon to have very "deep" properties in the wild, but I can't help but wonder if there is a smarter approach to this.

Of course, any other feedback is welcome --- always looking to improve the code!

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Optimize

### 1.1 Get rid of clones

Let's take a look what JsonElement::Clone() does. See [JsonElement::Clone()](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b2d5d63e5194265e18c448d7f014585bf0bad2d4/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Document/JsonElement.cs#L1440).
It calls [JsonDocument:CloneElement(int index)](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b2d5d63e5194265e18c448d7f014585bf0bad2d4/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Document/JsonDocument.cs#L793). Which creates new internal JsonDocument & what's important: it doesn't disposes that document. The reason why you need to call `Clone()` - it's because you call `Dispose()` (via `using statement`). So if we stop calling `Dispose()`, we don't need to call `Clone()`

Well, you still need to call clone on `doc.RootElement`, because `doc` is passed outside - but it's only once in DynamicUpdate.

See [diff](https://github.com/vlova/CodeReviewPatchJson265739/commit/ad2f79b2ed707a6f3564cbb7ec86126e9ceb5cc7)

### 1.2 Get rid of serialize/deserialize newElement

So, you have next code:

```
string newJson = newElement.ToString();
…
return DynamicUpdate(entity, newJson, addPropertyIfNotExists, useTypeValidation, options);
```

So, here we creating `newJson` from existing data (`newElement`), because `DynamicUpdate` accept either `string` or `JsonDocument`, but not `JsonElement`. This can be easily fixed, because your overloads actually doesn't really need full `JsonDocument` to be present.

We can also notice that after such refactoring we don't need to pass `JsonDocumentOptions options` everywhere.

See [diff](https://github.com/vlova/CodeReviewPatchJson265739/commit/d63a11152025b418dae740ffb701c92d804aa7a0)

### 1.3 Get rid of serialize/deserialize oldElement

So, now we have next code

```
string oldJson = oldElement.GetRawText();
IDictionary<string, object> entity = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(oldJson);
return DynamicUpdate(entity, newElement, addPropertyIfNotExists, useTypeValidation);
```

So, `DynamicUpdate` requires us to pass `ExpandoObject` as entity. And what we have - is `JsonElement`.

There are no way to get rid of such conversion. But we are doing too much during in our existing implementation - serializing & deserializing. What we need - is to touch our top-level properties only (because nested properties will be touched on other rounds of serializing). Let's write our manual implementation:

```
private static ExpandoObject ToExpandoObject(JsonElement jsonElement)
{
    var obj = new ExpandoObject();
    foreach (var property in jsonElement.EnumerateObject())
    {
        (obj as IDictionary<string, object>)[property.Name] = property.Value;
    }

    return obj;
}
```

See [diff](https://github.com/vlova/CodeReviewPatchJson265739/commit/a3f735f929bb99751ab06e7945944337611054e7#diff-e8c9f036b174ca0668defb35667f7482834224e2e14492830e893dcd2be29159)

## 1.4 Get rid of serialize/deserialize entity

So, you have next lines:

```
JsonDocument finalDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(JsonSerializer.Serialize(entity));
return finalDoc.RootElement;
```

Why do we need that? Because entity is `IDictionary<string, object>` and inside of `GetNewValue` we return either `JsonElement newElement` or updated object, which can't be be `JsonElement`.

Let's use `object` as return type so we don't need to convert anything.

See [diff](https://github.com/vlova/CodeReviewPatchJson265739/commit/e5f142906ac55a12cc72dc934634bffc2a345295)

## 2. Refactor

### 2.1 Get rid of returning data

Returning data violates [CQS](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Command%E2%80%93query_separation). And in our case — for nothing.

Each overload of `DynamicUpdate` returns data. In two cases (when accepting `string` or `JsonDocument`) it's not required. In third case (`JsonElement`) we "need" that because of next contents in `GetNewValue`:

```
return DynamicUpdate(ToExpandoObject(oldElement), newElement, addPropertyIfNotExists, useTypeValidation);
```

Well, but `DynamicUpdate` modifies `ToExpandoObject(oldElement)`, so we can return it:

```
var oldObject = ToExpandoObject(oldElement);
DynamicUpdate(oldObject, newElement, addPropertyIfNotExists, useTypeValidation);
return oldObject;
```

See [diff](https://github.com/vlova/CodeReviewPatchJson265739/commit/815509bea840901f4cc0559082df221957185f4d#diff-e8c9f036b174ca0668defb35667f7482834224e2e14492830e893dcd2be29159)

### 2.2 Introduce DynamicUpdateOptions

So, you have the next parameters:

```
bool addPropertyIfNotExists = false,
bool useTypeValidation = true
```

These parameters are options/settings. They should be moved into separate class in order to preserve maintainability. Just imagine what will happen in case if you need to add one more option. This also will reduce the number of parameters from 4-5 to 3-4. See [Refactoring: introduce parameter object](https://refactoring.guru/introduce-parameter-object)

See [diff](https://github.com/vlova/CodeReviewPatchJson265739/commit/b38a51d6142330d7d2f8d146cca16936d5be34ef#diff-e8c9f036b174ca0668defb35667f7482834224e2e14492830e893dcd2be29159)

## 2.3 Extract resolving JsonProperty

Inside of DynamicUpdate you have next lines:

```
bool hasProperty = entity.TryGetValue(propertyName, out object oldValue);

// sanity checks
JsonElement? oldElement = null;
if (oldValue != null)
{
    if (!oldValue.GetType().IsAssignableTo(typeof(JsonElement)))
        throw new ArgumentException($"Type mismatch. Must be {nameof(JsonElement)}.", nameof(entity));
    oldElement = (JsonElement)oldValue;
}
```

These lines are not good, because they pollute code & violate [Single level of abstraction principle](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction)

So we will extract this code to new `GetJsonProperty` method. In order to do that we also need to introduce `var hasProperty = entity.ContainsKey(propertyName);` inside of `DynamicUpdate` - because we don't want to `GetJsonProperty` to return both object & flag.

See [diff](https://github.com/vlova/CodeReviewPatchJson265739/commit/9843c3d86a27ce1332888a019fc03d3c1a27903f#diff-e8c9f036b174ca0668defb35667f7482834224e2e14492830e893dcd2be29159)

## 2.3.1 Reduce nesting in GetJsonProperty

We have nested `if` inside of getting property. This is not good.
Now, when we have separate method, we can easily refactor it.
Let's apply [Refactoring "Replace nested conditional with guard clauses"](https://refactoring.guru/replace-nested-conditional-with-guard-clauses):

```
entity.TryGetValue(propertyName, out object oldValue);

if (oldValue == null)
    return null;

if (!oldValue.GetType().IsAssignableTo(typeof(JsonElement)))
    throw new ArgumentException($"Type mismatch. Must be {nameof(JsonElement)}.", nameof(entity));

return (JsonElement)oldValue;
```

See [diff](https://github.com/vlova/CodeReviewPatchJson265739/commit/89ee88b8ddecd51c4d8561ac7a374667a7597447#diff-e8c9f036b174ca0668defb35667f7482834224e2e14492830e893dcd2be29159)

## 2.4 Avoid executing redundant code

So, your code has next nice line:

```
if (!hasProperty && !updateOptions.AddPropertyIfNotExists) continue;
```

But this line is executed after resolving `newElement` and `oldElement`.
Let's fix it!

See [diff](https://github.com/vlova/CodeReviewPatchJson265739/commit/c193f61c8cc901970fddd46118bb95849d4c9858#diff-e8c9f036b174ca0668defb35667f7482834224e2e14492830e893dcd2be29159)

## 2.5 Do not expose API over IDictionary<string, object>

So, you built extension over `IDictionary<string, object>`.
But your code assumes that nested objects will be of type JsonElement.
What if we will use your code over Newtonsoft.Json deserializer?
What if we will use your code over JsonConverter which performs nested deserialization of ExpandObject (like DynamicJsonConverter in https://www.codetd.com/en/article/8462216)?

Well, your code will fail in runtime. This is really bad for you.

Instead public instances of this method should accept either `JsonDocument` or `string` and return updated content. As we don't know required parsing options, it's better to accept `JsonDocument`.

We will return `IDictionary<string, object>` from `DynamicUpdate`. Maybe it's not totally good idea, because ExpandoObject will contain JsonElements inside — and this is not something that we will expect to see in IDictionary. But I'm afraid that we will do too much work in case if we will choose to return `JsonDocument` or `string`.

By this we also made version of method without side-effects - and this is much way better than previous.

By this we also can simplify contents of `GetNewValue`.

See [diff](https://github.com/vlova/CodeReviewPatchJson265739/commit/c8ac91834f633179c1f6ab45bb143b812c4f4ed5#diff-e8c9f036b174ca0668defb35667f7482834224e2e14492830e893dcd2be29159)

## 3. Support more cases

## 3.1 Support arrays

I'm not going to provide code for it. Probably you already know that your implementation doesn't works with arrays properly.

## 4. Beautify

### 4.1 Naming

1. `DynamicUpdate` → `GetPatched` / `Patch`; and:

   - `DynamicUpdateOptions` → `PatchOptions`
     -`updateOptions` → `patchOptions`
2. `entity` → `toPatch`
3. `patchJson`, `doc` → `patch`
4. `convertedEntity` → `patched`
5. `jsonProperty` → `patchChildProp`:

   - Also, `newElement` is dropped in favor of `patchChildProp.Value`
6. `hasProperty` → `toPatchHasProperty`
7. Inside of `DynamicUpdate` (which is `Patch` now): `oldElement` → `toPatchChild`
8. `GetNewValue` → `GetPatched`, because well, it's really the same as our main method
9. Inside of `GetNewValue` (which is now `GetPatched`): `oldElementNullable` → `documentToPatch`, `oldElement` → `original,` oldElement`→` newElement`→`patch`

See [diff](https://github.com/vlova/CodeReviewPatchJson265739/commit/8c1fa1eeaf9b7274053132c411dfd025ce44a0d3#diff-e8c9f036b174ca0668defb35667f7482834224e2e14492830e893dcd2be29159)

### 4.2 var

Your code contains variables with explicit types even when they are obvious. See:

```
JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(patch, jsonDocumentOptions);
JsonElement oldElement = (JsonElement)toPatch;
```

Some code styles doesn't allow it, but let's leverage [var](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) everywhere.

See [diff](https://github.com/vlova/CodeReviewPatchJson265739/commit/1733a22bcf31c600787b18a7d6b15d1e96809b5b#diff-e8c9f036b174ca0668defb35667f7482834224e2e14492830e893dcd2be29159)

### 4.3 Comments

See [Best practices for writing code comments](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/07/05/best-practices-for-writing-code-comments/)

Inside of your extensions all comments are duplicating code:

```
// type validation
if (patchOptions.UseTypeValidation && !IsValidType(oldElement, patch))
```

and

```
// recursively go down the tree for objects
if (oldElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Object)
{
    return GetPatched(oldElement, patch, patchOptions);
}
```

Let's drop it.

### 4.4 if/for consistent formatting

There are 3 styles of formatting inside of your codebase. You should pick one. I suggest to pick next as most typical for C#-codebase:

```
if (…) {
    …
}
```

See [diff](https://github.com/vlova/CodeReviewPatchJson265739/commit/639a094bc64821087b459542b0e5e561f374de59#diff-e8c9f036b174ca0668defb35667f7482834224e2e14492830e893dcd2be29159)

### 4.5 Consistent null-guards

In some cases you have null-guards, in some not.
Let's do

See [diff](https://github.com/vlova/CodeReviewPatchJson265739/commit/c5849f560fe5c8e6c43e5d9615462460dec317bd#diff-e8c9f036b174ca0668defb35667f7482834224e2e14492830e893dcd2be29159)

## Alternative solutions

1. Consider implementing [JSON Patch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
2. Consider the next idea:

   1. Deserialize json into IDictionary<> in deep manner. See https://www.codetd.com/en/article/8462216.

      ```
      IDictionary<> DeserializeDynamicDeep(string json)` {
         …
      }
      ```
   2. Write method that merges deeply two IDictionary<>.

      ```
      IDictionary<> GetPatched(IDictionary<> toPatch, IDictionary<> patch) {
         …
      }
      ```
   3. Write sugar method that allows to work you with json/streams

      ```
      public static string GetPatched(string toPatch, string patch)
         => GetPatched(
                DeserializeDynamicDeep(toPatch),
                DeserializeDynamicDeep(patch)
            );
      ```

## Final solution

You can see it on [github/CodeReviewPatchJson265739](https://github.com/vlova/CodeReviewPatchJson265739/blob/master/CodeReviewPatchJson265739/JsonExtensions.cs) or directly here.

Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace CodeReviewPatchJson265739
{
    public static class JsonExtensions
    {
        public static IDictionary<string, object> GetPatched(
            this JsonDocument toPatch,
            string patch,
            PatchOptions patchOptions = default,
            JsonDocumentOptions jsonDocumentOptions = default)
        {
            if (toPatch == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(toPatch));
            }

            if (patch == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(patch));
            }

            using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(patch, jsonDocumentOptions);
            return GetPatched(toPatch, doc, patchOptions);
        }

        public static IDictionary<string, object> GetPatched(
            this JsonDocument toPatch,
            JsonDocument patch,
            PatchOptions patchOptions = default)
        {
            if (toPatch == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(toPatch));
            }

            if (patch == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(patch));
            }

            return GetPatched(toPatch.RootElement.Clone(), patch.RootElement.Clone(), patchOptions);
        }

        private static IDictionary<string, object> GetPatched(
            JsonElement toPatch,
            JsonElement patch,
            PatchOptions patchOptions)
        {
            var patched = ToExpandoObject(toPatch);
            Patch(patched, patch, patchOptions);
            return patched;
        }

        private static void Patch(
            IDictionary<string, object> toPatch,
            JsonElement patch,
            PatchOptions patchOptions)
        {
            patchOptions ??= new PatchOptions();

            if (patch.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Object)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Only objects are supported.");
            }

            foreach (var patchChildProp in patch.EnumerateObject())
            {
                var propertyName = patchChildProp.Name;
                var toPatchHasProperty = toPatch.ContainsKey(propertyName);
                if (!toPatchHasProperty && !patchOptions.AddPropertyIfNotExists) continue;

                var toPatchChild = GetJsonProperty(toPatch, propertyName);
                toPatch[propertyName] = GetPatched(
                    toPatchChild, patchChildProp.Value, propertyName,
                    patchOptions);
            }
        }

        private static JsonElement? GetJsonProperty(IDictionary<string, object> entity, string propertyName)
        {
            entity.TryGetValue(propertyName, out var oldValue);

            if (oldValue == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (!oldValue.GetType().IsAssignableTo(typeof(JsonElement)))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Type mismatch. Must be {nameof(JsonElement)}.", nameof(entity));
            }

            return (JsonElement)oldValue;
        }

        private static object GetPatched(
            JsonElement? toPatch,
            JsonElement patch,
            string propertyName,
            PatchOptions patchOptions)
        {
            if (toPatch == null)
            {
                return patch;
            }

            var oldElement = (JsonElement)toPatch;

            if (patchOptions.UseTypeValidation && !IsValidType(oldElement, patch))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Type mismatch. The property '{propertyName}' must be of type '{oldElement.ValueKind}'.", nameof(patch));
            }

            if (oldElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Object)
            {
                return GetPatched(oldElement, patch, patchOptions);
            }

            return patch;
        }

        public class PatchOptions
        {
            public bool AddPropertyIfNotExists { get; set; } = false;

            public bool UseTypeValidation { get; set; } = true;
        }

        private static ExpandoObject ToExpandoObject(JsonElement jsonElement)
        {
            var obj = new ExpandoObject();
            foreach (var property in jsonElement.EnumerateObject())
            {
                (obj as IDictionary<string, object>)[property.Name] = property.Value;
            }

            return obj;
        }

        private static bool IsValidType(JsonElement oldElement, JsonElement newElement)
        {
            if (newElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (oldElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.True && newElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.False)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (oldElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.False && newElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.True)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return (oldElement.ValueKind == newElement.ValueKind);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

````
string original = @"{""foo"":[1,2,3],""parent"":{""childInt"":1},""bar"":""example""}";
string patch = @"{""foo"":[9,8,7],""parent"":{""childInt"":9,""childString"":""woot!""},""bar"":null}";
Console.WriteLine(original);

// change this value to see the different types of patching method
bool addPropertyIfNotExists = false;

// patch it!
var expandoObject = JsonDocument.Parse(original).GetPatched(patch, new JsonExtensions.PatchOptions
{
    AddPropertyIfNotExists = addPropertyIfNotExists
});
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(expandoObject));
```
````